# How to add between-output contraints to Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Given the model

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape[1])
out = keras.layers.Dense(78, activation='relu')(inputs)
out = keras.layers.Dense(54, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(54, activation='relu')(out)
out = keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1])(out)

X.shape is [:3], y.shape is [:5]
```

I need to introduce the constraint that y[1] >= y[0], e.g. if the current output vector is `[0.74, 0.69, 0.32, 0,54, 0.44]` it must be changed to `[0.74, 0.74, 0.32, 0,54, 0.44]`.

Possible solution: introduce a Lambda layer and use a custom function

```
out = keras.layers.Lambda(constrainOut)(out)

def constrainOut(x): #not actual code
   for i in x:
       if i[1] > i[0]:
           ...
```

Problem is that in constrainOut AFAIK i can't easily pick up the vectors and change them. The function is invoked in the building of the computation graph and not during actual computation, so there is no numeric vector in `x` yet. In lambda layers, functions can only operate on tensor as a whole, and the list of possible operations is confined to the overloaded operators of the tensor object and compiled into the graph. Am I right? and if so, what could be possibly another solution?

Comment: From your statement `the constraint that y[1] >= y[0], e.g. if the current output vector`, what does y mean ? Does it mean the output from any hidden layer or the labels ? Generally `y` is used to denote the labels or dependent variables in machine learning.

Comment: Also if `y` means output from any hidden layers, I could not think of any use case of the problem described.

Comment: This is a regression model, not a classificator. There are no labels The last layer is linear, the input and output are vectors of reals. The outputs are coherent with the inputs (e.g. similar inputs give similar outputs in the training set, and there is partial linearity between some inputs and some outputs). Inputs and outputs are normalized, since the parameters have different units. y is the output of the last layer, to be compared with the test set